# Share redis connection between django views

Tags: django, redis, django-views, connection-pooling, redis-py

While debugging I've noticed that each redis accessing django view uses a separate redis connection.

Why is this so?
Is django using a thread per view and redis-py creates a connection per thread? Or is it some other reason?

How can I make django share a single connection between the various views?

Comment: Are there reasons for deviating from this? If it works and performs well it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Guess.. Django should be using pooling

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell redis client to use an existing connection pool rather then create a new one.

The easiest way to do this is to create a connection pool and reference it somewhere (module level, a class instance you reuse etc etc) and reuse it; as you can see redis.Redis accepts a connection_poll parameter.